# Fitting Tabulars inside page limits

Tags: tables, indentation, adjustwidth

I'd like to limit a tabular element (not a table) to make it fit inside the page limits. It is indented by default and I'd like to have the same indentation on the right side as well. Both columns should be equally long.

This is what I have right now, but it goes beyond the page limits.

```
\paragraph{Un/happiness}
Unhappiness refers to misery, when the mood is in the speaker, or antipathy, when the feeling is directed at you.
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    Surge of behaviour: \textit{whimper, cry, wail, rubbish, abuse, revile} & Surge of behaviour: \textit{quejarse, llorar, gemir, lamentarse, sollozar, berrear} \\
    Disposition: \textit{down, sad, miserable} & Disposition: \textit{triste, deprimido, con la depre}
\end{tabular}
```

I had to include `\vspace{o.5}` because it does not leave any blanks above the tabular, although it does below, which is another issue with my tabulars.

Comment: Welcome! Can you complete your code so we can compile it?

Comment: If I complete your code in the obvious way, the tabular is not indented. It rather starts to the right of the line ending with `directed at you.` The `\vspace` is not going to do anything at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tabularx` for equal width columns which expand to fill a given width.

You can determine the width by subtracting twice the paragraph indentation from the current line width. To make this easy, load `calc`.

Finally, you may find you get lots of bad boxes and ill-looking lines if you have narrow widths with justified text. In that case, consider using ragged-right columns. You can create ragged right `tabularx` columns by defining a new type of column with the `array` package. Below, I've used `L`.

This example shows one example with the default `tabularx` `X` columns and one with the `L` columns.

[image: 2 examples]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,calc,array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Un/happiness}
Unhappiness refers to misery, when the mood is in the speaker, or antipathy, when the feeling is directed at you.
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth-2\parindent}{XX}
  Surge of behaviour: \textit{whimper, cry, wail, rubbish, abuse, revile} & Surge of behaviour: \textit{quejarse, llorar, gemir, lamentarse, sollozar, berrear} \\
  Disposition: \textit{down, sad, miserable} & Disposition: \textit{triste, deprimido, con la depre}
\end{tabularx}
\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth-2\parindent}{LL}
  Surge of behaviour: \textit{whimper, cry, wail, rubbish, abuse, revile} & Surge of behaviour: \textit{quejarse, llorar, gemir, lamentarse, sollozar, berrear} \\
  Disposition: \textit{down, sad, miserable} & Disposition: \textit{triste, deprimido, con la depre}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `tabularx` with this code:

```
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    Surge of behaviour: \textit{whimper, cry, wail, rubbish, abuse, revile} & Surge of behaviour: \textit{quejarse, llorar, gemir, lamentarse, sollozar, berrear} \\
    Disposition: \textit{down, sad, miserable} & Disposition: \textit{triste, deprimido, con la depre}
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually do what was asked though.

Comment: @cfr: Oh! I misread the requirements. I'll delete my suggestion. B.t.w., wouldn't it be as simple to make `\tabcolsep=\parindent` (and use a `\noindent before the table, of course) without havind to load `calc`?

Comment: What if you don't want to change the spacing between the two columns of the table?

Comment: Or `@{\hspace{\parindent}}` on both sides, or even `@{\quad}`  for the standard value of 1em.

Comment: I don't think that is `as simple`. Perhaps if by `simple` you mean something like `complicated and scary-looking` ;).

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different from *@cfr* answer -- without use of package `cal`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Un/happiness}
Unhappiness refers to misery, when the mood is in the speaker, or antipathy, when the feeling is directed at you.
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\parindent\relax}{LL}% <--
  Surge of behaviour: \textit{whimper, cry, wail, rubbish, abuse, revile} 
    & Surge of behaviour: \textit{quejarse, llorar, gemir, lamentarse, sollozar, berrear} \\
  Disposition: \textit{down, sad, miserable} 
    & Disposition: \textit{triste, deprimido, con la depre}
\end{tabularx}
\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\parindent\relax}{LL}% <--
  Surge of behaviour: \textit{whimper, cry, wail, rubbish, abuse, revile} 
    & Surge of behaviour: \textit{quejarse, llorar, gemir, lamentarse, sollozar, berrear} \\
  Disposition: \textit{down, sad, miserable} 
    & Disposition: \textit{triste, deprimido, con la depre}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]